# How to set max image size in Joi/Hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I am using nodejs+mongodb. In the front-end while uploading the image it doesn't allow if the size is more than 50kb. I want to set it upto 5MB so that I can upload the image if the size is 1MB or 2MB. I have tried many way I have googled it but still I dint get proper solution.
I checked in this link [Joi/hapi][1]

[1]: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.1/API.md but still did not work. Can anybody please help me

Here is my schema

```
const nameofSchema = Joi.object().keys({
description: Joi.string(), // .required(),
image: Joi.string().max(500000),

category: Joi.string(),
namesasd: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*$/),
title: Joi.string(), // .required(),
price: Joi.number().integer(),
tag: Joi.object().keys({
    tag_name: Joi.string()
})
});
```

In this for **image** I want to set max limit size 5mb.(to upload upto 5mb size image)

Below is route

```
create: {
    description: '',
    path: '/',
    verb: 'post'
},
```

Answer (score 13):

You wouldn't use Joi to set the file size limit. This is a [route configuration](https://hapijs.com/api#route-options) option.  You would set the `config.payload.maxBytes` property to the number of bytes you want. The default is 1 Mb. Small example:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/upload',
  config: {
    payload: {
      maxBytes: 1000 * 1000 * 5, // 5 Mb
      output: 'stream',
      parse: true
    },
    validate: {
      payload: {
        file: Joi.any()
      }
    }
  },
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    /* do stuff with your file */
  }
}
```

Comment: @Carlos what part aren't you understanding? Can edit your original question to include your route configuration so I can get some more context?

Comment: for image field I want to set max limit like now user not able to upload more that 40kb size image. so I want set limit like 2mb or 5mb. Ok I will add my route above